# Pandas top n values in each group

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
item      date       hour     value
  a         4         12       123
  a         6         11        54
  b         1          7       146
  c         8          1        97
  a         9          5        10
  c         4          5       114
  b         1          7       200
...       ...        ...       ...
```

and I want to keep the top 10 `item` by `value` (discard the rest is ok), regardless any other column. They are not sorted.

Following my input example, and as I didn't write enough to get 10 from every item, the expected output would be something like this if I want the top 1:

```
item      date       hour     value
  a         4         12       123
  c         4          5       114
  b         1          7       200
...       ...        ...       ...
```

I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168397/pandas-get-top-10-values-after-grouping) but I'm not sure how to tell pandas to take `value` for the calculation.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an input data frame and the expected output?

Comment: `df.groupby('item')['value'].nlargest(10)`  the many dupes cover some other options

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both `['item', 'value']` and then [`groupby.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df.sort_values(['item', 'value'], ascending=False).groupby('item').head(10)
```

---

Or with `nlargest`:

```
df.groupby('item').value.nlargest(10).reset_index()
```